# Vite - How to npm run dev when I have deleted both package-lock and package.jason folders?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install, npm-package

Im following along a tutorial on YT on how to code and deploy a react website. I created my project using Vite. Everything was reflecting fine on my browser window until I closed the terminal and now my browser returned "This page can't be reached". So I tried running `npm run dev` one more time and I get a bunch of errors. Looked online for an answer and ended up deleting both the `package-lock.json` and `package.json` folders. Now when I run `npm install` I only get a rather almost empty `package-lock.json` folder. Is there a way to undo this? I feel like I messed around too much with the terminal. How can I go back to running `npm run dev` effectively?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the packages again,

You need to initialize the package again.
I'd suggest going through the source code in order to find out the name of the packages.
`npm init`
then all you need to do is
`npm i pkg1 pkg2 pkg3`

Comment: Awesome, after a little bit of digging it worked, thanks!